# Getting objects from Parse Relation that were added in this save

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have a Parse Class **Group** and there is a parse relation field in it, called **people** (users, who are in this group). I am implementing a afterSave on "Group". I want to notify users, who are just added by admin into this group.

How do i do that ?

```
 Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Group, function(request){
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

  var group = request.object;
  var relation = group.relation("people");

  //How to get users that are added on this save.

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the new records being added to a relation, you need to inspect the `relationsToAdd` property of a `Relation` (its an array):

`var newRecords = request.object.op("people").relationsToAdd;`

I know this works in `beforeSave` but have not used it in `afterSave` tirggers

Comment: newRecords is a array ?

Comment: And one more thing. If i am removing objects from that relation, then the newRecords would be the objects that are being removed ???

Comment: No. You need to access `relationsToRemove` array.

Comment: Thanks Man .. Worked Awesome